# javascript div background image not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I am trying to display a div with an image in its background in my aspx page. The image's name is 'PathFindingMap' ( a png file) and is located in the "images" folder. The "images" folder is in the same directory as the aspx page. However, nothing is shown on the page.

In the .aspx page's client side, i have the following code snippet:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="floorPlan.aspx.cs" Inherits="ipsWebs.floorPlan" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1"  runat="server">
                        <div class="ClsdrawArea" id="draw_area" style="width: 100%; height:100%; background-image: url('images/PathFindingMap.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size:cover">
                            </div>

</asp:Content>
```

In the chrome browser, i pressed f5 and checked on the Network and it says the image "PathFindingMap" is loaded. However, i could not see anything on the web page. I tried to copy and paste the similar code "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

width and height doesnt work when you set background image to a div. 
 give height and width in pixels or use bootstrap.

```
style="width: 100px; height:100px;
```

see [example plnkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/6tFJptXza38YF7J6ivHu?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You are setting background-image to a block element.It takes width 100% by default.But height 0px.So you need to set haight some pixel to show background.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing the `Build Action` to `Content` and `Copy to Output Directory` property of the image to `Copy if newer`?